# Defining Activity for Close Questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, editing

A lot of closed questions keep popping up on the front page because someone has added a comment to an answer.

While technically this is activity, could the definition be tightened up for closed question to allow them to die a graceful death?  Maybe have it so no activity on them other than re-open or question edits count?

I am suspicious that there are people keeping their questions alive in the hope that they'll be re-opened...

Answer (score 5):

Considering that there are questions that some think should not have been closed at all, that activity will hopefully give those questions views -> and hopefully votes to re-open.

Maybe after a certain period of time, once the community has had the opportunity to see those questions and agree that they should stay closed, it would make sense. Recently closed questions should stay as they are IMO.

Comment: +1. I agree. With more and more questions being posted (either directly or through migrations), it's becoming harder to keep an eye out for things. The only recourse for people who think their questions were wrongly closed is to convince others to vote to reopen, which can't be done if nobody sees the post. Abuse of post "bumps" can be taken care of by mods through locking a post or delete votes.

Comment: I agree a certain grace period could / should exist to give people the chance to vote to reopen, but there are questions that are closed within a couple of hours that are still kicking around a week later because they're continually being nudged back up which seems wrong.  Perhaps a reopen vote being part of the activity which would bunk a question back up would help (if that's not already the case)?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you. But maybe we should change the behavior of the default view mode instead (when you click on the logo)?

I don't like the default view (activity). I prefer the "question" view with questions sorted by date for that reason.

Comment: I think activity is a good view, because there are still some great questions which are under-answered. When you stumble upon one and answer it, it's nice that others can read your answer and also provide their own. (In particular, this is nice for the question asker, who may not want to put up a second bounty on their question.)

Comment: There is a big **unanswered** button in then main menu for that.